Showing that $V_{S} \subseteq \Pi_{S}$?
From Aaaron Harrow's Lecture series: Quantum Information Science II, Lecture on stabilizers, I am a little confused with one of the details of the following proof.
Claim 1. $$\Pi_{S} = \frac{1}{|S|} \sum_{g \in S} g$$
In the proof, he first shows that $\Pi_{S}$ is a projector and has eigenvalues $0$ or $1$. He then goes about showing that Im$\Pi_{S}=V_{S}$ (where $V_{S}$ is the vector space that defines the quantum stabilizer code i.e. consisting of all of the states that are stabilized by $S$). The proof for $Im \Pi_{S} = V_{S}$ goes as follows:
For $g \in S$, and for any $| \psi \rangle$, $$g\Pi_{S}|\psi \rangle = \Pi_{S} | \psi \rangle,$$ meaning Im$(\Pi_{S}) \subseteq V_{S}$. I understand this.
However, we are then told that if $| \psi \rangle \in V_{S}$, then $$\Pi_{S} |\psi \rangle = | \psi \rangle,$$
and therefore $V_{S} \subseteq \Pi_{S}.$

Can someone help to clarify:

why $\Pi_{S}|\psi \rangle = | \psi \rangle$ means $V_{S} \subseteq \Pi_{S}$? To me, $\Pi_{S}|\psi \rangle = | \psi \rangle$ only shows that $\Pi_{S}$ stabilizes $|\psi \rangle$ which we would expect.


The image $\mathrm{Im}(\Pi)$ is defined as the subspace
$$
\mathrm{Im}(\Pi) := \{|v\rangle \, \mid \, \exists\, |w \rangle, \quad |v\rangle = \Pi |w\rangle\} 
$$
you can check that this is indeed a subspace.
We say for two subspaces that $V \subseteq W$ if for all $|v\rangle \in V$ we also have $|v\rangle \in W$. But then take any $|v\rangle \in V$ if we have $\Pi |v\rangle  = |v\rangle$ then clearly by the definition of $\mathrm{Im}(\Pi)$ above we also have $|v\rangle \in \mathrm{Im}(\Pi)$. Thus $V \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(\Pi)$.
